# timestamps in laravel 5.2.7 have default null values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm using `Laravel Framework version 5.2.7`. I cretaed a database migration as shown below:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLessonsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('lessons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->boolean('some_bool');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('lessons');
    }
}
```

I went in the virtual machine's MySql database and used the command `desc lessons;`, this is what I'm getting: [image]

I don't understand why do `created_at` and `updated_at` colums have `NULL` as the `Default`.
I went to Laravel 5.2 documentation and saw this:

`$table->timestamps();  Adds created_at and updated_at columns.`
`$table->nullableTimestamps();  Same as timestamps(), except allows NULLs.`

**So according to the documentation `$table->timestamps();` should not allow `NULL` as `Default`. But still I'm getting `created_at` and `updated_at` colums having `NULL` as the `Default`. I'm confused. Please HELP!!**

Infact these colums shoul be like this table:[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `$table->timestamp('created_at')` instead of `$table-timestamps()` in your schema builder, default value will be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and it won't be `NULL`.

Likewise to store update time of a record: 
`$table->timestamp('updated_at')`.

The difference is in just a letter **'s'** and have to mention the column name such as `created_at`/`created`, `updated_at`/`updated`.

Comment: `$table->timestamp('added_on');` - takes CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but
 `$table->timestamp('created_date');` does not.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a heads-up, since Laravel 5.2.14 timestamps were made nullable by default.

Blueprint.php:

```php
    /**
     * Add nullable creation and update timestamps to the table.
     *
     * @param  int  $precision
     * @return void
     */
    public function timestamps($precision = 0)
    {
        $this->timestamp('created_at', $precision)->nullable();

        $this->timestamp('updated_at', $precision)->nullable();
    }
```

The discussion around this can be read on Github.

> Taylor Otwell: Personally I think ->timestamps() should just default to ->nullableTimestamps() to solve this issue.

From Github issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12060#issuecomment-179249086

Changed in commit: Make timestamps nullable by default
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/720a116897a4cc6780fa22f34d30c5986eafc581

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is answering the question or not but...

The default `timestamp` method (at least in Laravel 5.4) outputs the following SQL:

```
`my_new_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Which is what you are looking for. If you set a `timestamp` column to be `nullable`, the default value will be `NULL` as well as allowing null.

So:

```
$table->timestamp('my_new_timestamp')->nullable();
```

Would give the following SQL:

```
`my_new_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't allow `NULL` as you see in the column `Null`, they are all set to `NO`

Comment: I updated my question. I wanted to know why don't `created_at` and `updated_at` have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as `Defaut`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 5.5 :

```
$table->timestamp('returned_at')->useCurrent();
```

Generates a column with `not null, default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#column-modifiers

Still true as of Laravel 9.x.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-modifiers